# Combine results of three IF Exists conditioned select statements results using union not working in Sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, union

I have three sql select statements with If Exists() as format like below:

```
IF exists(
Select 1 * from table1
)
IF exists(
Select 2 * from table2
)
IF exists(
Select 3 * from table3
)
```

The three table results returns the same columns but they are having different calculations inside if. Now I get separate three tables as results, I need to join them as a single table I tried with Union but not worked.Any suggestions welcome.

**EDIT**
The Result Now I'm getting as like :

```
Table1 ===> From |   To  | Hours

Table2====> From | To | Hours

Table3===> From | To | Hours
```

I need all these tables values in a single table.these three tables values may or may not contains more than one rows or null values(No rows)

Comment: For `UNION` to work along with the same number and order of columns the data type of the columns should also be compatible. Does your table1, table2 & table3 have them in common.

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, not images.

Comment: No the tables datatypes are different. I return the columns as same for all the three tables...What else need to do for this ?

Comment: I have added expected result @jarlh..Hope so you can get it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why the `union` not work for you, but you don't need to use `exists` if you are using `union all` :

```
select t1.col1, t1.col2
from table1 t1
union all
select t2.col1, t2.col2
from table2 t2
union all
select t3.col1, t3.col2
from table3 t3;
```

**Note :**

- There must be same number of expressions/columns in all `SELECT` 
  statements.
- The corresponding expressions/columns must have the same data type in the `SELECT` statements.

Comment: I already worked in it these not helped in my case bro.Any how thanks for your suggestions!

Comment: @SPYder . . . I'm upvoting because I think this correctly answers your question.

Comment: Yes It's right answer too...In my case I solved it using Temp table concept!

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem with the help of my friend using a #Temp table.Each time I get values from one table and I insert it into temp table like wise for all the tables values.
At last I print the temp table value.As I expected got the result too!. Thanks SO.